# how to use different commands for the same program in C

Tags: c

im relatively new to C (~1 week), i wanted to make a calculator such that when i type `2*2` in the console it gives the solution, how do i do this?

the options i got from the #C IRC is to use [link](https://www.mankier.com/2/link) or [symlink](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html), it would mean making billions of them

i found out when i type `python3` and then type `2*2`, python gives the output as 4 correctly
i wonder how it is done so i can implement it in my program as well (but make it such that it executes directly from the terminal)?

Comment: It works in Python because `2 * 2` is a valid Python statement. It doesn't work in a shell because that's not a valid command. If you want to make a program that parses input and attempt to evaluate the input as expressions or statements, you're making an *interpreter*. In short you're writing a language (perhaps a very simple one, but still a language). You can make it work just like Python, and read line by line from the standard input, and then parse/evaluate each line. You can't make it work by attempting to run the expressions or statements in the shell, your application must be running.

Comment: Neither `link` nor `symlink` have anything to do with a calculator? I'm really confused what you picked up from that IRC

Comment: @UnholySheep as in use it to symlink to other files in /usr/local/src like `2`, `8753`, etc but that would be very tedious and near impossible task

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i see, so ill have to write my own shell (or modify my current shell (dash)) for that functionality?

Comment: Unless you want to modify an existing shell (to make it widely incompatible with any other shells and environments) the correct term would be that you write a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Comment: calculations from a bash shell are done with $((2*2)) echo $((2*2)) . You need to learn more C before coming here and wanting to write expressions parsers :)

Comment: Symlinks are definitely the wrong answer for the task you're describing. if you want a shell that evaluates expressions with no command name before them to tell it that this is what you want done, you need to find or write a shell which has that behavior. Normal approach would be to just write a program  which evaluates it's command line arguments as an expression and evaluates that, and use that program name before the expression... Or, if your shell has it, to use the built-in command which does exactly that.